# Java script carousel not working with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, carousel

I was trying to add carousel in AngularJS with simple JavaScript code but its working fine with `w3school.com` with JavaScript only but same is not working when I have implemented in AngularJS.

I do not want to use any library for carousel.

Below code is working fine with `w3school.com`

```
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow
```

But when I have implemented this in AngularJS its not working. I am getting `slide.length` value `0`.

Below is AngularJS code:-

```
$scope.showCarousel = function(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  console.log(slides);
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  console.log(slides.length);
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
    console.log(slides[i].style);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //    $scope.style1 = {'display': 'block'};
  slides[$scope.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[$scope.slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: The W3Schools demo manipulates the dom, which is not needed in Angular. In Angular you can  set a variable to the slide you need, and bind that variable to your template using `{{ }}` syntax

Comment: Yes i have done same but before binding the style i am not getting slide.length value, its 0 due to this code is not working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this once, I  have changed the code from w3c school and try to make it with angular

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" ng-click="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" ng-click="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" ng-click="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" ng-click="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" ng-click="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

$scope.showSlides=function(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
$scope.showSlides(slideIndex);

$scope.plusSlides=function(n){
  $scope.showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

$scope.currentSlide=function(n){
  $scope.showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}



});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working fine with above code.But when i am implementing in my code its returning style.length value 0. I have pasted same code. this is the output of slides in console. HTMLCollection []
0
:
div#mySlide1.col-lg-12.mySlides
1
:
div.col-lg-12.mySlides
length
:
2
mySlide1
:
div#mySlide1.col-lg-12.mySlides
__proto__
:
HTMLCollection

Comment: Are you getting this error in the code given by me?

Comment: Actually you are getting this because you have consoled the slides in your code i.e. console.log(slides); where you have all the divs with class mySlides and it's simply printing that. It's not a error. It's the HTML elements which are in the slides variable. HTMLCollection is referring these.

Comment: yes but when i am trying to print console.log(slides[0]) its undefined.

Comment: Your code is working fine but when same i have implemented in my code but its generating an error "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" which is due to its unable to read slides.

Comment: <div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>



<script>

var x=document.getElementsByClassName("a");
console.log(x[0]);
  

</script>

Comment: var x=document.getElementsByClassName("a");
console.log(x[0]['style']);

Comment: it's reading slides but calling style with dot is giving this error as it's not an object at's an associate array

Comment: Like I said in my comment, you should’t use `document.getElementsByClassName()` in Angular.... DOM manipulation is handled for you by Angular 